# Definition of Holomorphic map of complex manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, terminology

Let $X,Y$ be complex manifolds and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. When exactly do we say that $f$ is "holomorphic"? I am interested in the basic definition (possibly using charts), not an equivalent characterization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a point of $X$, then we say $f$ is holomorphic at $p$ if there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ on $X$ with $p \in U$, and a chart $(V, \psi)$ on $Y$ with $\phi(p) \in V$, such that $f(U) \subseteq V$ and the induced map

$$
\phi(U) \stackrel{\phi^{-1}}\longrightarrow U \stackrel{f}{\to} V \stackrel{\psi}{\to}\mathbb{C}^n
$$

is holomorphic in the familiar sense (using $\phi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$).

We say $f$ is holomorphic if it is holomorphic at all points.

Comment: Do we say that if $f$ satisfies the property you described using charts for a point $p$, then it is "locally holomorphic"?